# How to open a jquery ui dialog box from an iframe on a click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

I am trying to open a jquery ui dialog box from an iframe. When the button is clicked to open the dialog box, the dialog box is suppose to display over the iframe like a bootstrap modal.

The problem I am having is when I click a button to open the dialog box it opens the entire page of the other file inside the dialog box.

myIframeFile.asp:

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="myFileToOpenTheDialogBox.asp?a=<%=Request.QueryString("a")%>"></iframe>
```

myFileToOpenTheDialogBox.asp:

```
   <button id="btnOptions">Options</button>

    <div id="dialog" title="Options" style="display:none;">
      <form>
        ...
      </form>
    </div>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#btnOptions").click(function(){
         $("#myiframe", window.parent.document).dialog({
            width:800,
            resizable: true
         });
      });
    });
</script>
```